# PlatformIO monitor_speed not working. Setting Ignored in .platformio.ini

Tags: monitor, platformio, baud-rate

This has been working for me in the past 2 years -- and all of sudden stopped working. Opening the Monitor always occurs at the default 9600 baud.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PlatforIO ... but to no avail.
Is there an additional setting that may be corrupt?
Has anyone seen this issue before?
[Simple Blinky test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvXOz.png)

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone ever stumbles on this ... It was fixed in the last Platformio update ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).